# Datadog Monitor via Terraform: Invalid operator

Tags: terraform, datadog

When I try to roll out my terraform code containing the following `datadog_monitor`

```
resource "datadog_monitor" "test_alert" {
  name               = "Test alert"
  type               = "log alert"
  message            = "Test alert message @test@example.com"

  query = "logs('service:myservice Some log message').index('main').rollup('count').last('5m') > 0"

  enable_logs_sample  = true
  notify_no_data      = false
  include_tags        = true

  tags = ["tag1:tag1value", "tag2:tag2value"]
}
```

this results in the following error message:

```
Error: error validating monitor: 400 Bad Request: {"errors": ["The value provided for parameter 'query' is invalid: invalid operator specified: "]}
```

According to the [API description](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/monitors/#create-a-monitor), the query field for log alerts should have this syntax: `logs(query).index(index_name).rollup(rollup_method[, measure]).last(time_window) operator #`, and `>` is listed as a valid operator.

Other questions in this field listed solutions that were largely unrelated to the error message, so I assume the issue is unrelated to the operator, but I haven't been able to figure out the issue so far.

Comment: Have you tried using backslash escaping? e.g. `query = "logs(\"status:error env:staging\").index(\"main\").rollup(\"count\").by(\"service\").last(\"5m\") > 100"`

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by [sonata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/498238/sonata), the problem was solved using backslack escaped double-quotes instead of single-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this for people who may face the same issue, in case you specified a wrong alert type, the datadog API will raise 400 bad request with query invalid anyway;
so make sure `type = "log alert"`.